# conditional where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I need filter result of a join query between two tables but I don't have a condition for the "where clause".

What I need is to filter based on id_project like this:

1. if id_project is equal to 24 *(24 is the default project)* then it should return only rows with
   id_project =24. **here rows 1,3...10 will be selected**
2. if id_project is equal to 25, then I need those rows which have id_project=25 plus those rows which has " id_project=24 and not id_project 25, **so rows number 2 to 11 will be selected**

With this query :

```
SELECT tp.id_tag, tp.id_project, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
    FROM instrumentation.dbo.tag_project tp
    INNER JOIN instrumentation.dbo.tag_level tl
    ON tl.id_tag=tp.id_tag
// 
where tl.id_level=69  and tp.node_level=1
```

I get this result :

[image]

How can I change my query to do this?

Comment: How is your `WHERE` related to your requirement at all? You haven't mentioned id_level or node_level. _"Rows which has " id_project=24 and not id_project 25"_ Is it possible that a row can have id_project=24 **and**   id_project=25 in the same time?

Comment: Also provide sample data, create a [sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/1) that we can use for testing.

Comment: Maybe I'm to stupid for this. But why don't you add the `and id_project= 24` or `and id_project=25` to it?

Comment: because its not just basic and/or,

Comment: I have clarify it in the end of line Tim. ==>  rows number 2 to 11 will be selected

Comment: it means between two first rows, the first row will not be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking a little more about your request, it burns down to: For every id_tag give me the ID requested, or 24 if not available. This can be done in one query, where you use a ranking with ROW_NUMBER, in which you prefer the requested ID over the 24.

```
select *
from
(
  select
    tp.*,
    row_number() over(partition by id_tag 
                      order by case when id_project = 24 then 2 else 1 end) as rn
  from tag_project tp
  where id_project in (24, @REQUESTED_ID)
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Here is your original query changed accordingly:

```
SELECT id_tag, id_project, NJTagName, node_level, id_level
FROM
(
  SELECT tp.id_tag, tp.id_project, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
       , row_number() over (partition by tp.id_tag order by case when tp.id_project = 24 then 2 else 1 end) as rn 
      FROM instrumentation.dbo.tag_project tp
      INNER JOIN instrumentation.dbo.tag_level tl ON tl.id_tag=tp.id_tag
  WHERE tl.id_level=69 AND tp.node_level=1 
  AND tp.id_project in (24, @REQUESTED_ID)
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So depending of whether the user asks for ID 24 or not there are two different queries to execute.

Here is the query for ID 24:

```
select *
from tag_project
where id_project = 24;
```

Here is the query for @OTHERID. We use UNION ALL to combine the 24 records with the @OTHER records. And we use NOT EXISTS in order to avoid certain records.

```
select *
from tag_project
where id_project = @OTHERID
union all
select *
from tag_project tp
where id_project = 24
and not exists
(
  select *
  from tag_project tp2
  where tp2.id_tag = tp.id_tag
  and tp2.id_project = @OTHERID
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `in`:

```
SELECT tp.id_tag, tp.id_project, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
    FROM instrumentation.dbo.tag_project tp
    INNER JOIN instrumentation.dbo.tag_level tl
    ON tl.id_tag=tp.id_tag
// 
where tl.id_level=69  and tp.node_level=1 
and tp.id_project in (24, @OTHERID)
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want only one id_project instead, use can also use aggregation method.

```
SELECT tp.id_tag, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
       case when count(distinct tp.id_project) = 2 then @OTHERID
            else 24 end as id_project
  FROM instrumentation.dbo.tag_project tp
 INNER JOIN instrumentation.dbo.tag_level tl
    ON tl.id_tag=tp.id_tag
 WHERE tl.id_level=69  and tp.node_level=1 
   AND tp.id_project in (24, @OTHERID)
 GROUP BY tp.id_tag, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
```

Comment: this still selects both rows number 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this for default case pass @otherId as `NULL`.

```
SELECT tp.id_tag, tp.id_project, tp.NJTagName, tp.node_level , tl.id_level
    FROM instrumentation.dbo.tag_project tp
    INNER JOIN instrumentation.dbo.tag_level tl
    ON tl.id_tag=tp.id_tag
where tl.id_level=69  and tp.node_level=1 AND tp.id_project = ISnull(@otherId, 24)
```